# Xubuntu: Can I align the clock / notification / wifi etc area to the right - like win xp?

Tags: xubuntu, notification

Hi and sorry for a simple question...this is my first Linux installation for about a decade.

Fresh Xubuntu Install, in light of XP end.

I can't seem to align my clock, wifi info, skype status, lanuguage flag, Audio settings, or username to the right.  They float on the end of the panel jumping left and right anytime I close/open an application.

I'm an XP user, and am migrating to Linux.

I can cope with the learning curve and the differences, but I'd like things to be similar where possible. Having the clock and notification area locked to screen-right would be nice, simply for the consistence of always knowing where it is, but also to simplify seeing other apps in the panel. I don't know if I did something to break things (I almost certainly did) and make it float, but I can't seem to fix it.

I didn't want two (or more) virtual screens, so I think I deleted one, I wanted to simplify everything at first, meaning one screen only, then learn and grow from there.  It's possible (read: likely) that something I did allowed the clock etc to float.

Anyway, it's pretty annoying, watching that clock jumping back and forth.  Almost as annoying as how long this post has got.

I do thank you for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:

- `Add new item` to the panel and select `Separator`
- Drag the Separator and drop it between the windows icons and the notification area
- `Right-click` on the separator and access `Properties`
- Select `Transparent` and check `Expand`.

Now it should behave.

Comment: And behold, with a simple click of a mouse, the problem is fixed and balance restored. Thank you.